# struct super_block and ext2_super_block

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, ext4, ext2

Can anyone explain me the relation between struct ext2_super_block ( in fs/ext2/ext2.h) and struct super_block ( in include/linux/fs.h). I am asking this because, in LKP ( by Robert Love ) it says that each filesystem has to implement struct super_block. But ext2_super_block is different and how are the functions in super.c applied to ext2?

Answer (score 1):

`ext2_super_block` is ext2-specific on-disk structure as `super_block` is a generic in memory super block description.

Comment: Because every filesystem will implement its on super block, why does struct super_block exist?

Comment: just [compare ext2_super_block](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext2/ext2.h#L410) and [super_block](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1491) by yourself :)